# How to change/yank the string between two blank spaces?

Tags: vim

How to change/yank the string between two blank spaces? I have tried `ci[hit space bar]` but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 24):

Use `ciW` (**c**hange **i**nner **W**ORD)

From `:h WORD` :

```
A WORD consists of a sequence of non-blank characters, separated with white
space.  An empty line is also considered to be a WORD.
```

Comment: W is capital W ( I make a mistake just now)

Answer (score 3):

It is `w` for word, not , i.e. change inner word `ciw` or yank inner word `yiw`, respectively.

**Update** for the given example, let `|` denote the carret

```
id="remember_me" name="_r|emember_me" value="on"
```

Hit `ciW`

```
id="remember_me" | value="on"
```

Comment: Imagine I have this string `id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on"` and my cursor is at second attribute, and I want to remove the whole attribute. I think in that case the bes way should be a keybinding to remove the string between the blank spaces.

Comment: For those wondering, this doesn't work because the answer is ciW, because in Vim the capital W counts words as inside spaces https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106425/what-is-difference-between-w-and-w-in-escape-mode-of-vim